# Eclipse debugger fails to start

Tags: eclipse, debugging, spring-tool-suite

For the last few days, I have been getting the following error whenever I try to debug a project.

```
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/core/model/JDIDebugTarget (wrong name: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/core/model/JDIDebugTarget$AjcClosure1)
```

This problem occurs with every project in every workspace, even in a workspace I created after the problem started manifesting. Whether or not I have set any breakpoints, the problem still occurs.

I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.8.1, and I can still run projects, just not debug them.

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to version 3.8.4 of STS and I can now debug my projects. Something in my previous STS installation must have broken.